# How customize multiple fields in a Symfony form template?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form in a Symfony 3.4 project. I can render it properly, this is what I get:

```
<form name="registration" method="post">
    <div id="registration">
        <div>
            <label for="registration_email" class="required">E-mail címed</label>
            <input type="email" id="registration_email" name="registration[email]" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="registration_name" class="required">Vezetékneved és keresztneved</label>
            <input type="text" id="registration_name" name="registration[name]" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="registration_password" class="required">Jelszó</label>
            <input type="password" id="registration_password" name="registration[password]" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="registration_password_repeat" class="required">Jelszó újra</label>
            <input type="password" id="registration_password_repeat" name="registration[password_repeat]" required="required" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="registration_submit" name="registration[submit]" class="btn btn-primary">Regisztráció</button>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="registration__token" name="registration[_token]" value="r8KLMX7OCB6tDWJzHOp8_U-P4MjLI3PiOLTeJsvUXTY">
    </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to make each form field wrapped inside a div which has a "`form-group`" class. For this I have to customize all field types one by one, like:

```
{% block text_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block password_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block email_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to apply this to all kind of field types?, like:

```
{% block *_widget %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. First of all I want to overwrite the `row` not the `widget`, and instead of naming a specific type, I have to use `form_row`, so instead `{% block text_row %}` I need `{% block form_row %}` and this applies to all type of input rows.